# Ant failing to run handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, ant, handlebars.js

I'm running an ant build.xml file that contains this:

```
<macrodef name="handlebars">
<attribute name="dir" default="" />
<attribute name="outfile" />
<element name="args" optional="true" />
<sequential>
    <exec executable="handlebars"
        dir="@{dir}"
        output="@{outfile}"
        logError="true"
        failonerror="true">
            <args />
    </exec>
</sequential>
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
<handlebars outfile="${dev.dir}/js/templates/hbs.js">
<args>
    <arg value="-f" />
    <arg value="${dev.dir}/js/templates" />
</args>
```

This, I think, should work, but I'm getting the following error:

> D:\build.xml:32: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "handlebars" (in directory
>   "D:\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I can run handlebars from the command line manually so it should work... I assume it's choking on  I'm doing this on a windows machine and handlebars is installed through node.js which is in my system path... I think I might need to add handlebars to the path, but, I'm not sure how I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is hunting for this the answer was:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe">
 <arg line="/c handlebars templates -f templates/hbs.js" />
</exec>
```

Needs to be cleaned up a bit, but that's it.